# Wordpress have_posts() returning false

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display the page content for a normal wordpress page; simplest thing to do in wordpress right? Well, for some reason on every single page it cannot find this content.

I have tried re-saving permalinks, re-saving each page, updating the site, re-installing WP.

Here is the code that checks it:

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) : // This is where it fails
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'page' );
        endwhile;

    else :
        get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'missing' );
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: I have found that if I only put
`<?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'page' ); ?>`
Then it displays fine. But why is the IF statement failing?

Comment: write query to check it has posts or not